# Prolog - find an item in a list without built-in predicates

Tags: list, prolog

I want to create a predicate that is TRUE if the element I search for is NOT in the list.

And that's without any built-in predicates or arithmetic constructions.

I am such a beginner in prolog and i'm thinking way too much in oop languages at the moment.

Thanks for a nice tipp in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog - how to check if a list includes certain elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188084/prolog-how-to-check-if-a-list-includes-certain-elements)

Comment: Sounds like you may want to get Prolog book and/or check one of the several online Prolog tutorials (Google "prolog tutorial") to get into a Prolog mindset. Once you have the very basics of Prolog, I think the answer for how to do what you want will become evident.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: That's **not** a duplicate!

Comment: The ISO Prolog Core standard specifies `call/1`, `!/0`, and `fail/0` as control constructs, not as built-in predicates. On the other hand, `\+/1` is specified as a built-in predicate. But with those three control constructs you can define your own negation-as-failure predicate and then use it to solve this problem efficiently. However, some Prolog systems blur this distinction between control constructs and built-in predicates. Thus, looking at your question and the answers so far (including my own!), it's not clear which control constructs are allowed and which are off limits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will work:

```
not_in( _ , []    ) .  % By definition, the empty list contains nothing.
not_in( X , [X|_] ) :- % If the head of the non-empty list matches,
  !, fail .            %   we fail with prejudice.
not_in( X , [_|L] ) :- % otherwise,
  not_in( X , L )      %   simply recurse down on the tail.
  .
```

alternatively, you can do something like this: a negated, positive test:

```
is_member_of( X , [X|_]) .  % Success! The head of the list matches the desired item.
is_member_of( X , [_|L]) :- % otherwise...
  is_member_of( X , L )     %   recurse down on the tail.
  .

is_not_a_member_of( X , L ) :-
  \+ is_member_of( X , L ) .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_without([], _).
list_without([E|Es], F) :-
   dif(E,F),
   list_without(Es, F).
```

Is the closest one can get. It does use `dif/2` which is a built-in predicate. But there is no other way to express inequality in a sound manner. See [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) for more.

This definition can be used in various ways:

Regular testing:

```
?- list_without([a,b,c],d).
   true.
```

But also more general cases:

```
?- list_without([a,b,c],X).
   dif(X, c), dif(X, b), dif(X, a).
?- list_without([a,b,c],X), X = a.
   false.
?- list_without([a,b,c],X), X = d.
   X = d.
?- list_without([a,b,E],d).
   dif(E, d).
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both the list and the element to test are **ground**, plus that standard control constructs are not classified as built-in predicates, a solution would be:

```
list_without(List, Element) :-
    list_without(List, Element, Copy),
    equal(List, Copy).

list_without([], _, []).
list_without([Head| Tail], Element, Copy) :-
    (   equal(Head, Element) ->
        list_without(Tail, Element, Copy)
    ;   Copy = [Head| TailCopy],
        list_without(Tail, Element, TailCopy)
    ).

equal(Term, Term).
```

Some sample queries:

```
?- [list_without].
true.

?- list_without([1,2,3], 4).
true.

?- list_without([1,2,3], 2).
false.

?- list_without([1,2,3], 3).
false.

?- list_without([1,2,3], 1).
false.
```

But this is a rather odd exercise...