# How to make a predcate which validates the values from one list to another in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I have 2 lists (A and B). I want to use the values in B to check if A complies to them.

Ex1:

```
A=[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
B=[1, 3]
```

In this case is true. Because we have in A one 1 and three 1s.

Ex2:
In these ones is false

```
A=[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
A=[1, 1, 1, 0,0,0,1]
```

it not keeps the order

Any ideas where to start?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "validate" them? That there is one one followed by three consecutive ones?

Comment: [I think this is what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188084/prolog-how-to-check-if-a-list-includes-certain-elements)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, that is what I need.

Comment: @Aizzaac: are the ones always separated by **exactly one** 0?

Comment: Yes. Is the way to validate. I need the 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to solve the problem, let's analyze it: you want to validate that `A` is some sort of encoding of `B`. If `B` contains a number `b0` then `a` should contain an `0` followed by `b0` ones, and so on, and `0`s are used as separators.

So let's first implement a function: `validate_single(Bi,A,AT)` that checks for a single `Bi` if `A` contains `Bi` ones and the remainder of the list is unified with `TA`. We can easily implement this like:

```
validate_single(0,A,A).
validate_single(N,[1|T],R) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    validate_single(N1,T,R).
```

Now we only need to validate that the `validate_single` works for every element of `B` and perform *chaining* on the `A` such that the result on one `validate_single` is passed further and further. We also need to check that the separators are valid. We can do this with:

```
validate([0],[]).
validate([0|A],[Bi|BT]) :-
    validate_single(Bi,A,AT),
    validate(AT,BT).
```

So here `validate([0|A],[Bi|B]) :- ...` will "pop" an `0` from the head of the `A` list and then aim to validate a single subsequence, if that works, it will continue with the tail of the subsequence `AT` and the tail of `B`, `BT` until we finally reach the end the list and we expect one `0` located at the end.

Or putting it all together:

```
validate([0],[]).
validate([0|A],[Bi|BT]) :-
    validate_single(Bi,A,AT),
    validate(AT,BT).

validate_single(0,A,A).
validate_single(N,[1|T],R) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    validate_single(N1,T,R).
```