# Prolog , check if a pair of elements appears in a list

Tags: list, if-statement, search, prolog

Given a list `L` I would like to see if a pair `P`, appears in the list. If the element is found, then print `*Found*`.

For example:

```
L = [3,1,2,5,4,7].
P = (2,5).
```

Given this example, I should get `*Found*` as `2,5` appears on 2nd and 3rd position in list `L`.

Here is my approach , but I am getting a **false** answer.

```
search_pair([_|[]],_).
search_pair([X|T],(F,L)) :-
   first(Y, T),
   write('searching: '),write(F),write(' '),write(L),nl,
   write('trying: '),write(X),write(' '),write(Y),nl,
   ((F == L , L = Y) -> (write('Found'))
   search_pair(T,(F,L),R).
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog - how to check if a list includes certain elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188084/prolog-how-to-check-if-a-list-includes-certain-elements)

Comment: i am searching for a consecutive pair , this is the thing :/

Comment: You have syntax errors in line 6, a missing closing paren and a comma. Also, 'first' is not defined, and I assume your last line should call search_pair/2 and not search_pair/3, which is also undefined

Comment: This is much easier than you're making it. You can describe a list of at least two elements as, `[X, Y | T]` where `T` is the rest of the list (may be empty `[]`). And the rest of that list excluding the first element is `[Y | T]`.

Comment: Do not mix side effects with the actual program logic.

Answer (score 3):

The actual relation is quite easy to describe. There are two cases:

- case 1: The list starts with the given pair. In this case we're done.
- case 2: Otherwise we need to keep searching in the tail of the list.

This can be written with [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159) and [(',')/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36431808/6101159) like so:

```
pair_in((X,Y),[A,B|Cs]) :-
   if_((X=A,Y=B),
       true,                    % <- case 1
       pair_in((X,Y),[B|Cs])).  % <- case 2
```

Querying this with your example and a counterexample:

```
   ?- pair_in((2,5),[3,1,2,5,4,7]).
yes
   ?- pair_in((2,4),[3,1,2,5,4,7]).
no
```

If you want to output the message `*Found*` in the case of success, I would suggest to relocate that to a calling predicate, e.g. your predicate `search_pair/2`:

```
search_pair(L,P) :-        % <- calling predicate
   pair_in(P,L),           % <- actual relation
   format('*Found*~n').    % <- output
```

Now let's query this predicate with the above examples:

```
   ?- search_pair([3,1,2,5,4,7],(2,5)).
*Found*
yes
   ?- search_pair([3,1,2,5,4,7],(2,4)).
no
```

As you can see `*Found*` is only displayed in the case of success. That is because in case the goal `pair_in(P,L)` fails, Prolog doesn't move on to the next goal, since the rule cannot become true any more.

Comment: OP asked for "if", probably meant `if_`.